# Parsing an Internet page line after line

Tags: perl

Firstly I'd like to apology - I'm new to Perl, and my question is so basic I am almost sure it had been asked before, but sadly I couldn't find it.

I'd like to parse an Internet page like I parse a text file with the `open my $file, "<", ".."`. That is, I'd like to use a loop: `while (my $line = <$file>)`. Sadly I couldn't find a way to do that; only using LWP::UserAgent with some get's and content, but that gives me the whole Internet page. I could make an array out of it by splitting it with respect to \n, but I really want to use the convenience of `<$file>`.

What can I do?

Thank you very much and sorry again if it had been asked before.

Comment: How about getting the page content into a scalar variable (e.g. `$page`) and opening a file handle on it with `open(my $fh, "<", \$page)`?  For more info see (http://jclark.org/weblog/2004/09/24/scalario/)

Comment: Well, that seems to work sufficiently. Thank you very much!

Comment: Keep in mind that dealing with a web page line by line adds complexity to the parsing.

Comment: You can use also `for my $line ( split /\n/, $page) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->get('http://search.cpan.org/');

# assume a successful response

open(my $fh, "<", \$response->decoded_content);
while (<$fh>) {
  print "line $. has ", length($_), " characters\n";
}

# $fh will close when it goes out of scope.
```